# Punctuation in this case clear?

Tags: punctuation, commas, coordinating-conjunctions

I think in the first one, I don't need a comma before "and" cause they are short sentences. In the second however, I'm wondering whether I need the comma before "and" since it is a coordinating conjunction separating two main clauses... What do you say?

1) Yesterday, I went fishing,and John played cards.

2) In 2007, many people worked on the XY-Project, and several people were included in that process.

Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any commas in #1, but it would read more smoothly if you said, "I went fishing yesterday and John played cards."

#2 is confusing and/or redundant. **Several** means just a few. But you've just said **many** people worked on the XY-Project. So it seems that the "process" is different from the XY-Project. Or is it? Who can tell? The entire sentence needs to be reworked or split into two sentences. Merely adding or deleting commas won't fix it.

Comment: Don't take the content to seriously, take a similar example: In 2007, many people bought apples, and many supermarkets didn't have enough apples to sell.

Comment: is the comma before "and" mandatory? (since it is a coordinating conjunction joining two independent clauses?)